# Replicate cell from above in blank rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a data frame like this (including spaces):

```
1/4/2015    2   CREDT CARD SETTLEMENT





1/4/2015    3   Cash



1/4/2015    4   Cash
1/4/2015    5   Cash

1/4/2015    6   Cash
1/4/2015    7   Cash
1/4/2015    8   Cash
1/4/2015    9   Cash

1/4/2015    10  Cash
```

I wish to replicate the gaps in a way that they are filled by the previous number.

More specifically, I want this in the below format.

```
1/4/2015    2   CREDT CARD SETTLEMENT
            2    
            2    
            2    
            2    
            2    
1/4/2015    3   Cash
            3    
            3    
            3    
1/4/2015    4   Cash
1/4/2015    5   Cash
            5    
1/4/2015    6   Cash
1/4/2015    7   Cash
1/4/2015    8   Cash
1/4/2015    9   Cash
            10   
1/4/2015    10  Cash
```

I am new to Excel. Any simple explanation of how to do this is welcome.

Comment: please follow the two links & help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is organized in three columns, as below :

```
Col A    |  Col B  |  Col C
============================
1/1/2014 |    2    | Credit Card Transaction
         |         |
1/4/2014 |    3    | Cash
```

You could try this :

```
=if(A[n]="",B[n-1],B[n]+1)
```

where [n] is the current row number, and [n-1] is the previous row number.